# sapply - retain column names

Tags: r, sapply, r-colnames

I am trying to summarise the mean, sd etc for a number of different columns (variables) in my dataset. I have coded my own summarise function to return exactly what I need and am using `sapply` to apply this function to all the variables at once. It works fine, however the dataframe that is returned has no column names and I cannot seem to even rename them using a column number reference - aka they seem impossible to use in any way.

My code is below- as I am just finding summary statistics, I would like to just keen the same column (variable) names, with 4 rows (mean, sd, min, max). Is there any way at all to do this (even a slow way where I manually change the names of the columns)

```
 #GENERATING DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS
sfsum= function(x){
  mean=mean(x)
  sd=sd(x)
  min=min(x)
  max=max(x)
  
  return(c(mean,sd,min,max))
}

#
c= list(sfbalanced$age_child, sfbalanced$earnings_child, 
sfbalanced$logchildinc ,sfbalanced$p_inc84, sfbalanced$login84, 
sfbalanced$p_inc85, sfbalanced$login85, sfbalanced$p_inc86, 
sfbalanced$login86, sfbalanced$p_inc87, sfbalanced$login87, 
sfbalanced$p_inc88, sfbalanced$login88)

summ=sapply(c,sfsum)

names(summ)
 NULL
```

Comment: set the names of `c` with the column names.  Also, `c` is a function name, so it is better not to use that as an object name.  I think `sapply(sfbalanced, sfsum)` should get the output

Comment: `return(c(mean=mean,sd=sd,min=min,max=max))`

Answer (score 5):

If you provide names in return during the function definition, you can have rownames as function names, if you provide names of lists while defining your object then you can use `USE.NAMES` in `sapply` to get the names automatically.

An example on `mtcars` data can give you following output.

**Code**

```
sfsum= function(x){
    mean=mean(x)
    sd=sd(x)
    min=min(x)
    max=max(x)

    return(c("mean"=mean,"sd"=sd,"min" = min,"max" =max)) #For rownames
}

#
x= list("mpg" = mtcars$mpg, "disp" = mtcars$disp, "drat" = mtcars$drat)
#For column names

summ=sapply(x,sfsum, USE.NAMES = TRUE) #USE.NAMES = TRUE to get names on top
```

**Output**:

```
> summ
           mpg     disp      drat
mean 20.090625 230.7219 3.5965625
sd    6.026948 123.9387 0.5346787
min  10.400000  71.1000 2.7600000
max  33.900000 472.0000 4.9300000
```

Comment: `USE.NAMES = TRUE` is a default for `sapply`. The key is to return a named vector from the function.

Comment: And dataframe is already a list `x <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "disp", "drat")]`

Comment: @zx8754, I know , I just want to carry the same approach as OP to let him/her know where its coming from. Anyways thanks for the valuable inputs.

Answer (score 3):

If we need to have the column names as well, just loop through the dataset (assuming that we are applying the function on all the columns)

```
out <- sapply(df2, sfsum)
row.names(out) <- c('mean', 'sd', 'min', 'max')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4*4), 4, 4))
```